# How valuable and effective are spies and covert operations?

Tags: internal-consistency, geopolitics, espionage

So this is a fairly abstract question, as it is not really specific to a single setting, but how valuable are intelligence gathering and covert operations conducted by intelligence agencies in terms of actually influencing world affairs? For the purpose of my story idea, I'm questioning how valuable such a thing should be in terms of changing world affairs within a setting.

From what I've seen, I'm pretty sure they are far less valuable than they appear in most thrillers, but I haven't seen anything that has specifically assessed the value. There are arguments like [this one](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2008/09/29/the-madness-of-spies) from John le Carre, the famous thriller writer and former spy, about how many individual spies have delusions of grandeur and how at a larger scale this leads to cases like the lousy intelligence that led to the Iraq War.

There is also fairly significant evidence that Stuxnet was [mostly useless](https://www.cato.org/publications/commentary/cyberwar-iran-wont-work-heres-why) at slowing down the Iranian nuclear program and that other such operations had questionable value as well. An amusing case brought to light by James Risen is that of a Russain engineer working for the CIA who accidentally corrected the flaws in nuclear blueprints they were selling to Iran as part of an elaborate plot to confuse Iranian nuclear scientists with doctored plans.

The main argument you run into is that because we don't know about true scope of what is occurring, we also don't know how much they're successful behind the scenes.

Comment: Are you distinguishing between spies and covert operations (i.e. Hollywood stuff) versus general intelligence operations? I also think you shouldn't ignore how many resources are invested for the results obtained versus, for example, starting a war. If you spend a very small amount of resources a dozens times and only one of those is successful, but that saved you from spending a thousand times more, then it was pretty worth it even with all the failures. With a 1/12 success rate would you consider that effective? Surely its cost effective, but is it effective effective?

Comment: Any tool, *used properly* will be effective...and misused will be ineffective. What you ask them to do depends upon your goals and upon strategies to achieve those goals. You need good staff work to identify enemy key efforts and critical events that spies can look for and that covert teams can effect. If you pick the wrong effort or event, your agents' efforts are wasted. Lots of high-risk efforts fail: That's why it's called *risk*.

Comment: If this is about our world this is more a question for History.SE. if it's a world you're building we need more information about that world

Comment: This is much too broad.  Even examining espionage alone there is the potential to go back and forth comparing failures like those you list above with successes such as the British cracking Enigma or the Soviets using Fuchs and others to gain nuclear weapons a decade earlier than they could have otherwise.  Adding in special action and it becomes impossible to quantify because the alternative historical outcomes cannot be compared - if Alexander Litvinenko had not been successfully assassinated then how much more effective would opposition to Putin be? VTC unless more focus.

Comment: Basically your question is right. Ninety percent of all intelligence gathering is from public sources. Even from public sources in authoritarian countries. My source: Allen Dulles, *The Craft of Intelligence* (1963).  Dulles was in charge of the CIA, so he might know.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure they are far less valuable than they appear in most thrillers":* [Ultra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra) was rather important in the war effort of the UK against Germany; [Richard Sorge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Sorge) was rather important in letting Russia know that they could safely their armies from Siberia to the west; [Sicinnus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sicinnus) was rather effective in convincing the Persians to commit their fleet in the [Battle of Salamis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Salamis); and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Very**

If you go back to the around 500 BCE, you will find what is arguably the magnum opus on war and warfare, which is Sun Tzu's *Art of War*, which is so brilliantly written that, by and large, it's still relevant for the modern conversation of warfare. The final chapter of *Art of War* is entirely devoted to the care and management of spies and intelligence. To summarize it, intelligence and spies are no less significant to the war effort than entire armies.

For instance, WWII had a man named Juan Garcia, codenamed Garbo, possibly the greatest double-agent who ever lived and was awarded medals by *both* sides of the conflict - the Germans, who he developed a vast spy network for and fed valuable information including key details about D-Day; and from the British who he *actually* worked for, establishing an entirely fictitious network of agents and fed the Germans misinformation, including where the main thrust of the D-Day invasion was going to be. It would be an exaggeration to say that Garbo single-handedly turned the tide of the war, but it would not be one to say that the man saved thousands upon thousands of Allied lives over the course of the war.